# JMS automatically reconnecting to TOPIC

Tags: java, spring, jms, ibm-mq, spring-integration

I have two apps one app is publishing to a topic and another app is reading from that topic. We had a scenario where a queuemanager went down and then was available again. The publisher (without a restart) carries on working fine after the queuemanager restarts, but the topic consumer does not recieve the new messages from the publisher until it is restarted. Is there some configuration that can be setup on the topic consumer to refresh its connection somehow? We are using java / spring / spring integration over IBM MQ. The following is the configuration of our consumer.

```
<bean id="jmsAlertsServiceMessageListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="alertConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="alertsServiceTopic"/>
    <property name="autoStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="clientId" value="${ps.Alert.clientId}"/>
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="jmsTaskExecutor"/>
    <property name="subscriptionDurable" value="true"/>
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true"/>
    <property name="messageSelector" value="AlertState = 'RESOLVED'"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="alertsMessageListener"/>
    <property name="durableSubscriptionName" value="replay"/>
    <property name="recoveryInterval" value="30000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="alertConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory"  >
    <property name="transportType" value="1" />   
    <property name="queueManager" value="${alert.mq.qm}" />
    <property name="hostName" value="${alert.mq.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${alert.mq.port}" />
    <property name="channel" value="${alert.mq.channel}" />     
    <property name="SSLCipherSuite" value="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA" />        
    <property name="brokerPubQueue" value="${alert.mq.topic_connection_factory_broker_pub_queue}"/>
    <property name="brokerQueueManager" value="${alert.mq.topic_connection_factory_broker_queue_manager}"/>
    <property name="providerVersion" value="${alert.mq.topic_connection_factory_provider_version}"/>
    <property name="brokerVersion" value="1"/>       
    <property name="messageSelection" value="1"/>     
</bean>

<bean id="alertsServiceTopic" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopic">
    <constructor-arg value="${alert.mq.topic}" />
    <property name="brokerDurSubQueue" value="${alert.mq.queue}"/>        
    <property name="brokerVersion" value="1"/>          
</bean>

<bean id="alertsMessageListener" class="org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener">
    <property name="requestChannel" ref="alertsJmsInputChannel"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true"/>
    <property name="daemon" value="false"/>
    <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="jmsInbound-"/>
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="3"/>
    <!-- Discard any task that gets rejected. -->
    <property name="rejectedExecutionHandler">
        <bean class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$DiscardPolicy"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` will automatically reconnect according to the `recoveryInterval`.

Turn on DEBUG (or even TRACE) logging to figure out what's happening.